# two javascript syntax problem

Tags: javascript

These days I am reading some javascript source codes,however I found some syntax that I can not understand.

**1)the for-in loop**

```
var c;
var obj={name:'test',age:33};

for(var e in c={},obj){
    console.info(e+' = '+obj[e]);
}
```

**2)The Conditional Operator (?:)**

Generally,we use this operator this manner:

```
x > 0 ? x*y : -x*y
```

But I have seen some codes like this:

```
x > 0 ? (x*y,z=bar,..other expressoin) : (-x*y)
```

But it does not work if I change the comma to colon,it will throw a error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In both cases, the [*comma operator* <sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Comma_Operator) is used:

> You can use the comma operator when you want to include multiple expressions in a location that requires a single expression. The most common usage of this operator is to supply multiple parameters in a `for` loop.

And the [specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.14):

> #### [11.14   Comma Operator (  ,  )](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.14)
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> Expression :
>     AssignmentExpression
>     Expression , AssignmentExpression
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> **Semantics**
>
> The production *Expression : Expression , AssignmentExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating Expression.
> 2. Call GetValue(*lref*).
> 3. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating AssignmentExpression.
> 4. Return GetValue(*rref*).

That just means that *the result of the last expression is returned* as result of the whole "list" of expressions.

In the examples you gave, it is used for its [*side effects* <sup>[Wikipedia]</sup>](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29), namely evaluating every expression.
In general I'd say that this is *not such a good style* and, as you noticed, *more difficult to understand*.

```
for(var e in c={},obj)
```

is the same as

```
c = {};
for(var e in obj)
```

an does not seem to add any value. Even better would have been to just initialize `c` in the first line: `var c = {};`.

In case of the conditional operator: If `x > 0` is `true`, then all the expressions are evaluated and the result of the last expression is returned. In this case, using a normal `if` statement would be better (easier to understand).

Here again, the comma operator and maybe even the conditional operator seems to be used solely because of their side effects: Normally the conditional operator is supposed to only return a value but not to execute arbitrary expressions (a single function call which returns a value might be an exception).

---

As the MDN documentation says, it is more commonly used in a `for` loop to initialize multiple variables:

```
for(var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you can define variables like:

```
var obj1 = { a: 2, b: 4, c: 6};
var obj2 = { x: 1, y: 3, z: 5};
```

Or, you can comma-separate the declarations, like this:

```
var obj1 = { a: 2, b: 4, c: 6}, obj2 = { x: 1, y: 3, z: 5};
```

Now, a for in loop is normally something like:

```
for(var key in obj1) { console.log(key); }
```

But, if you comma-chain the part after 'in' it will allow it (just like when assigning), but will run the loop on the last object in the chain.

```
var key, obj1 = { a: 2, b: 4, c: 6}, obj2 = { x: 1, y: 3, z: 5};

// will output 'a', 'b' and 'c'
for(key in obj2, obj1) { console.log(key); }

// will output 'x', 'y' and 'z'
for(key in obj1, obj2) { console.log(key); }
```

This means you can assign values within the for in, and then do looping on another object.

```
var key, obj3; // obj3 === null

var obj1 = { a: 2, b: 4, c: 6}, obj2 = { x: 1, y: 3, z: 5};

// will output 'a', 'b' and 'c'
for(key in obj3 = { j: 9, k: 8, l: 7 }, obj1) { console.log(key); }

// obj 3 is now { j: 9, k: 8, l: 7 }
```

Okay, so now for the [ternary operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation). If the above makes sense, so should this.

Ternary operations are like if statements with a single line. You can't put semicolons in a line because then it becomes two or more lines. But putting () around comma-separated declarations then it is still considered one line.

So this is valid:

```
x > 0 ? a = 1 : a = 2;
```

And this is valid:

```
x > 0 ? (a = 1, b = 2) : (a = 2, b = 1);
```

But this is not, because the commas throw off the interpretation of the ternary:

```
x > 0 ? a = 1, b = 2 : a = 2, b = 1;
```

But I would not recommend setting values in a ternary, unless it looks something like:

```
a = x > 0 ? 1 : 2;
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

The first? no idea.  The second?  It's just like your typical inline if except it executes multiple expressions rather than one

```
x > 0 ? (doThis(),doThat(),x=2) : (again(),another(),y=5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the first one just an initializer?

```
var c;
var obj={name:'test',age:33};

for(var e in c=[], obj){
    console.info(e + ' = ' + obj[e]);
    c.push(e);
}

console.info(c);
```

Now, *why* you'd do it that way... I'm not sure.